# How to create a 2D array by scanning a file

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I'm trying  to read a file and generate a 2D Array. So I believe my constructor will create the correct dimensions, I just don't know how to input the actual values into the arrays.

File format:

```
6
1 4 2 2 2 3
4 2 2 4 1 2
2 1 3 4 3 2
1 3 3 2 6 2
0 0 0 2 0 0
3 4 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 6
5 0 1 0 0 4
```

The file input is on the left, and the board result should look like the right :

```
6             |       1 4 2 2 2 3 
1 4 2 2 2 3   |       -----------
4 2 2 4 1 2   |     1|. . . 2 . .|4
2 1 3 4 3 2   |     3|3 4 . . . .|2
1 3 3 2 6 2   |     3|. . . 1 . .|2
0 0 0 2 0 0   |     2|. 1 . . . .|4
3 4 0 0 0 0   |     6|. . . . . 6|1
0 0 0 1 0 0   |     2|5 . 1 . . 4|2
0 1 0 0 0 0   |       ----------- 
0 0 0 0 0 6   |       2 1 3 4 3 2
5 0 1 0 0 4   |
```

this first line of the file is the size of the board (6x6).

The second line is the "North to South(NS)" facing values

The third line is the "East to West(EW)" facing values

The fourth line is the "South to North(SN)" facing values

The fifth line is the "West to East(WE)" facing values.

And the rest of the lines will populate the board. A `0` will put nothing in.

```
public static final int EMPTY = 0;
int[][] board;
int dim;
int[] NS, SN, EW, WE; //the outter arrays



public SkyscraperConfig(Scanner f){

    while(f.hasNextLine()){
        if(f.nextLine().length() == 1){
            dim = f.nextInt();
        }
        else{

            outterArrays = f.nextLine().length();


            }


    }

    this.board = new int[dimension+1][dimension+1];//I made the dimension +1 to hold the outter arrays that hold the NS, SN, EW, and WE values
    this.NS = new int[outterArrays+1];
    this.SN = new int[outterArrays+1];
    this.EW = new int[outterArrays+1];
    this.WE = new int[outterArrays+1];



}
```

My Idea was to create a 2D Array that is the size of the first line in the file. Then for the outer values, create four arrays which will represent the outside. I don't know how to put those outer arrays into my 2D array though.

Comment: keeping track of the outer arrays separately is more work than its work. I would probably put them all in one array just make the 2d array 2 bigger in both directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all file reading, try to separate each task distinct task. Ask yourself "What do I need to know before I do , and what do I have to do in order to complete ?" Hopefully the tasks are listed in order (each task only requires information above it in the file), which is the case for your problem.

Your task seems to involve three sub tasks:

1. Figure out how large the arrays and matrix need to be (1 line)
2. Read in the side arrays (4 lines)
3. Read in the matrix (N lines)

So let's work with that:

```
int[][] board;
int dim;
int[] NS, SN, EW, WE; //the outter arrays

public SkyscraperConfig(Scanner f){
  //First line should be dimension line
  int dim = Integer.parseInt(f.nextLine());

  //Initalize data structures based off of this dimension
  this.NS = new int[dim];
  this.SN = new int[dim];
  this.EW = new int[dim];
  this.WE = new int[dim];
  this.board = new int[dim][dim];

  //Read in side arrays
  //...

  //Read in the board
  //...
}
```

Here we can guess that we're going to have a lot of duplicated code in reading the lines - probably time to start designing helper methods. One thing we seem to be doing a lot of is reading in a line and parsing all of the ints in it. So let's write a method for that

```
private static int[] parseIntLine(String line){
  String[] arr = line.trim().split(' '); //Split on the space character
  int[] intArr = new int[arr.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
  }
  return intArr;
}
```

Now we can use this method to finish up our implementation, letting the reading take care of the array length:

```
public SkyscraperConfig(Scanner f){
  //First line should be dimension line
  int dim = Integer.parseInt(f.nextLine());

  //Only actual initialization we have to do is for the matrix's outer array
  board = new int[dim][];

  //Read in side arrays
  NS = parseIntLine(f.nextLine());
  EW = parseIntLine(f.nextLine());
  SN = parseIntLine(f.nextLine());
  WE = parseIntLine(f.nextLine());

  //Read in the board - dim rows to read
  for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
    board[i] = parseIntLine(f.nextLine());
  }

  f.close();
}
```

Now there's a lot of things that could go wrong that you should probably account for. What if the first line contains more than just one number? What if the first line contains a non-integer value? What if one of the side arrays or one of the board rows is of the wrong length? What if there aren't enough rows to fill the board? What if there are too many rows? For each of these questions you should either handle the case within the method (via try/catch or if-else logic) or if it's an unfixable problem throw some kind of exception.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. just a quick question though. How can I print out my 2D array?

Comment: When I try to print the configuration I'm getting `SkyscraperConfig@4fca772d`

Comment: Chck out Arrays.deepToString(...)